# render messaging from a link_to without changing pages "ajax"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I currently have a basic messaging system. on some pages there is a send a message button. I want a popup to appear with the message ready to type in. I used this tutorial: [messaging system](https://medium.com/@danamulder/tutorial-create-a-simple-messaging-system-on-rails-d9b94b0fbca1#.h6rqx5asi)

- When clicking the message link, the path is to the conversations controller `create` so that the conversation gets created then gets redirected to the message for them to type the message.. this is all redirected to another page called `message.html.erb`.
- Iv attempted to make this popup, but i cant seem to figure out how to get through the conversations controller without redirecting to `message` page after create. I just want the user to click on the button and bam the message is ready to type.

**Conversations:**

```rails
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :authenticate_user!

def index
 @users = User.all
 @conversations = Conversation.all
 end

def create
 if Conversation.between(params[:sender_id],params[:recipient_id])
   .present?
    @conversation = Conversation.between(params[:sender_id],
     params[:recipient_id]).first
 else
  @conversation = Conversation.create!(conversation_params)
 end
 puts "convo created !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! path here needs to show up after click in partial"
 redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)

end

private
 def conversation_params
  params.permit(:sender_id, :recipient_id)
 end

end
```

**Messages:**

```rails
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action do
   @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])
  end

def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js

 @messages = @conversation.messages
  if @messages.length > 10
   @over_ten = true
   @messages = @messages[-10..-1]
  end
  if params[:m]
   @over_ten = false
   @messages = @conversation.messages
  end
 if @messages.last
  if @messages.last.user_id != current_user.id
   @messages.last.read = true;
  end
 end
@message = @conversation.messages.new




  end 


 end

def new
 @message = @conversation.messages.new
end

def create
 @message = @conversation.messages.new(message_params)
 if @message.save
  redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)
 end
end

private
 def message_params
  params.require(:message).permit(:body, :user_id)
 end
end
```

**My main page that i dont want to redirect from i want to stay on this page.**

```
<%= link_to conversations_path(sender_id: current_user.id, recipient_id: reservation.user.id), method: 'post', :remote => true do %>
     <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<% end %>
```

I made a folder called `messages` and `conversations` with `_message.html.erb` and `_conversation.html.erb`

- Would a possible solution be to run these in the backround on click? if so how would i do that? Im just not sure what approach i make with this as it needs to go through the `conversations_controller` first to find the conversation then the redirect in the controller happends.. is there a way to partial a partial or something?
- If you have another way of doing this then please or need more info!! i need this done very soon important, thank you! ^^